# Cypress do something after click

Tags: javascript, cypress, react-select

I have multiple components that contains react-select. I want to iterate through the components and get the values that are in react-select menu.

I tought It should work if I do it like this

```
cy.get(".flight-segment-times .css-10nd86i")
   .each(($select) => { 
          $select.click({ force: true }); 
          cy.get(".css-11unzgr").contains("option")
        })
```

But this doesn't work since the `.css-11unzgr` class appears only when it's parent element is clicked. However if I call `.click()` on `$select` element then dropdown menu won't even appear, if I call `.click({multiple: true})` directly on `cy.get(".flight-segment-times .css-10nd86i")` then every dropdown will sequentially open, but I need to be able to do something between those click actions.

Comment: I believe the class attributes - `.css-10nd86i`, `.css-11unzgr` are auto generated react components and must be dynamic for every reload. I would suggest your tests to get based on XPATH - e.g., `cy.xpath('//div[contains('attrib', 'value')]')`. Reference: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath

Comment: They are auto generated but the names are still the same. Targeting `.css-10nd86i` works. I will look into that xpath command, but I think the problem is that after clicking on `$select` dropdown menu won!t open, so It is not generated by react

Answer (score 0):

[`cy.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Arguments) (and other jquery-based commands) pass a jQuery collection to the callback, thus the `.click()` you are calling is actually a jQuery method, not a cypress command.

What you want to do is to [`cy.wrap()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html) it first:

```js
cy.get(".flight-segment-times .css-10nd86i")
    .each(($select) => { 
        cy.wrap($select).click({ force: true }); 
        cy.get(".css-11unzgr").contains("option");
    });
```

Comment: I tried that but It doesn't work. The dropdown menu won't open, which is strange because as I have written in OP if I try to use click method on the result of `get` command on first line then every dropdown will open

Comment: Weird that it reacts to jQuery-triggered `click`, but not on `cy.click`. From my tests, the above works fine --- but I haven't tried it on react app.

Answer (score 0):

just make it like two actions:

```js
cy.get(".flight-segment-times .css-10nd86i")
.click({ force: true })
cy.get(".css-11unzgr")
.contains("option")
```

But since you have problems with actually opening the React-Select component you are probably clicking the wrong component. What I do is find the class that holds the 'onMouseDown' property (that class is in our application called 'react-select__control'. If I click that element it does open.

To find out which class has the 'onMouseDown' property I use the React Developer Tools: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi